# Javascript - Get div height and apply in negative pixels

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to apply negative pixels on a div that comes from a variable

```
window.onscroll = function() {
var navBar = document.querySelector(".navBar");
var headerHeight = document.querySelector(".headerContainer").offsetHeight;
if ( window.pageYOffset > 100 ) {
    navBar.style.top = headerHeight + "px";
} else {
    navBar.style.top = "0px";
}
}
```

Basically, I have a fixed navbar and i want to apply some inline styles to **.navBar** class on scroll, If you look in the code you can see I'm getting the **.headerContainer** height and apply the pixels on navBar, But i want to apply in negative pixels, E.g. If headerHeight was 100px I want to apply -100px.

Its easy in jQuery but I cant figure this out in pure javascript, Big newbie here :)

Comment: Uh, if you want a negative value just multiply the number by `-1`? Also, `ta_hHeight` is an undeclared variable in your code.

Comment: What's the difference between jQuery and "native" JS here?

Comment: @Terry, Sorry i don't understand. What do you mean multiply the number by -1 :D as i said a big newbie here, Please give a simple example, BTW I edited my code above and changed the var name

Comment: Uhhh, 100 multiplied by -1 gives you -100? i.e. `navBar.style.top = (headerHeight * -1) + "px";`

Comment: Oh! Simple and smart. :P thanks a lot

Comment: @Nippledisaster Also in this other way > `"-"+headerHeight+"px"`

Comment: This seems to be a better solution without calculations. Thank you both :)